# How to save returned values of sql statements in Yii Migrations

Tags: php, sql, activerecord, yii

I am trying to build a Migration, where the output of one SQL statement needs to be parsed and then piped to the following migration statement .

`CDbMigration::execute()` does not have a return option, any ideas how to do this? 
[See Class Reference](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbMigration#execute-detail)

While I can run the query via ActiveRecord and parse the returned output, using active records in CDbMigration is not recommended, any better solution would be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the execute command will never return any results because it is designed to perform an execution, not a query - i.e. it sets some data in a table, rather than getting it.

Could you perhaps try this in either your up or down method as required:

```
$results = $this->getDBConnection()->createCommand($sql)->query();
```

though I would comment that if you need to do this, migration may not be the best tool for the job.

Comment: thank you, I totally forgot about executing direct sql statements without using ActiveRecords :), Yeah Yii migrations is not exactly the best tool for this sort of thing. But it is easier as I have a multi-server in different environments setup and use git for deployment. Setting up cron and push it through text files will probably take me a day :(

Comment: Then what tool should I use? I need to migrate data from "one to many" to "many to many" relation, converting a column into a separate table